# Calling overridden method

Tags: c#

Below shows my 3 classes: `Person`, `Employee` and `SalaryEmployee`.

Each class (from the right) inherits the class from the left side. E.g: `SalaryEmployee` inherits from `Employee`.

```
class Person
{
    private string address;
    private string name;

    public Person(string givenName, string givenAddress)
    {
        name = givenName;
        address = givenAddress;
    }

    public virtual void outputName()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("My name is " + name);
    }

    public void outputAddress()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("My address is " + address);
    }

    public void setName(string newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    public void setAddress(string newAddress)
    {
        address = newAddress;
    }
}

class Employee : Person
{
    private string NINumber;

    public Employee(string givenName, string givenAddress) : base(givenName, givenAddress)
    {
    }

    public void setNINumber(string givenNumber)
    {
        NINumber = givenNumber;
    }

    public void getNINumber()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("My National Insurance Number is " + NINumber);
    }
}

class SalaryEmployee : Employee
{
    private string name;
    private string address;

    public SalaryEmployee(string givenName, string givenAddress) : base(givenName, givenAddress)
    {
        name = givenName; address = givenAddress;
    }

    public override void outputName()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("My name is " + "S_" + name);  
    }
}
```

OOP is fairly new to me and I am trying to get the hang of inheritance. The problem I am facing is I have created an object called 'PersonFive':

```
SalaryEmployee personFive = new SalaryEmployee("Bob", "North Pole");
```

// Ignore the address 'North pole' I have used as a parameter, it's just used for this example.

I am able to call the `.outputName()` method, the output will be:

```
"My name is Bob"
```

However, the base method is called instead of the overridden method. The output I wanted it to give me was "My name is S_Bob"

Comment: I advise you to create really simple example in Console app and check the behaviour of the override methods..

Comment: Code works, but you shouldn't have to create a second "name" variable in SalaryEmployee.  The Person class should have a non-private Name property (you have a private field at the moment).  The output would then be "My name is S_" + base.Name;

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, you might didn't post the actual code that makes the error.

[image: The code output]

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer. It doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't have the privilege to comment at that time (below 15 points) but I tried to help. Now, you down-voted which toke another points. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: If you don't have the rep to comment, the right thing to do is move on, not add an "answer" which isn't actually an answer.